# Status of React Navigation drawer? (open or closed)

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I'm building a drawer with React Navigation and want to perform some logic if the user closes the drawer. I don't see anything obvious in the documentation that will allow me to do this. Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: do you find any solution, non of those works for me

Comment: How can I close the drawer **on the web**?? Clicking on the overlay doesn't close it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817071/react-navigation-how-to-close-the-drawer-menu-when-clicking-on-the-overlay

Answer (score 12):

You need to custom navigation actions to capture the `DrawerClose` event:

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    //...
});

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

    //use 'DrawerOpen' to capture drawer open event
    if (state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerClose') {
        console.log('DrawerClose');
        //write the code you want to deal with 'DrawerClose' event
    }
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Comment: In my case, for `"react-navigation": "^2.0.2"` I needed to check `action.type === 'Navigation/OPEN_DRAWER'` for it to detect the action. The `routeName` remains whatever is the Drawer Navigator name and not `DrawerOpen`.

Comment: How do I get listener for drawer within the screens, as this solution works in file where DrawerNavigator is created. what solutions do you have in mind for this use case?

Comment: @minimalist try this with screenProps, using Ricardo BM's technique I was able to wire it up in my homescreen by passing the router object into my app as a screenProps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248849/passing-props-from-a-root-component-through-a-bottomtabnavigator

Answer (score 6):

According to @ufxmeng

```
import {
  StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    //...
});

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerClose') {
        StatusBar.setHidden(false);
    }

    if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerOpen') {
        StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }


    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

See here https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/673b9d2877d7e84fbfbe2928305ead7e51b04835/docs/api/routers/Routers.md
and here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/699

Answer (score 5):

This is for anyone using the v2.0+ version of react-navigation. There are now drawer actions you can track.

```
{
  OPEN_DRAWER: 'Navigation/OPEN_DRAWER',
  CLOSE_DRAWER: 'Navigation/CLOSE_DRAWER',
  TOGGLE_DRAWER: 'Navigation/TOGGLE_DRAWER',
  DRAWER_OPENED: 'Navigation/DRAWER_OPENED',
  DRAWER_CLOSED: 'Navigation/DRAWER_CLOSED'
}
```

[react-navigation.js line 825](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/50320bf0d940b4872ceb22e7e41ec50c23d62027/flow/react-navigation.js#L825)

However, it seems that implied drawer navigations from say swiping don't fire the `OPEN_`/`CLOSE_` actions, since you didn't manually toggle it. The `_OPENED`/`_CLOSED` actions do fire afterwards, though.

```js
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(...);
const defaultGetStateForAction = MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Navigation/OPEN_DRAWER':
    case 'Navigation/DRAWER_OPENED':
      StatusBar.setHidden(true, 'slide');
      break;
      
    case 'Navigation/CLOSE_DRAWER':
    case 'Navigation/DRAWER_CLOSED':
      StatusBar.setHidden(false, 'slide');
      break;
    }

  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Comment: There's an issue open at the GitHub repo to implement a more direct API for this. Please post your use case there so it can be evaluated and handled accordingly. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-drawer/issues/5

Comment: Also note you can use `case 'Navigation/NAVIGATE'` if you need to hook into that too, as well as `case 'Navigation/BACK'`

Answer (score 2):

Working with "react-navigation": "^3.5.1"

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = DrawerNav.router.getStateForAction;

DrawerNav.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

    if(action){
        if(action.type == 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING' && action.willShow){   
            StatusBar.setHidden(true);
        } else if(action.type == 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING' && !action.willShow) {
            StatusBar.setHidden(false);
        }
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to wire it up such that the drawer events are available in one of your Screens or Components instead of the top level app, I was able to wire that up by using screenProps as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248849/passing-props-from-a-root-component-through-a-bottomtabnavigator). You first set up the screenProps on your app and pass in the router and whatever else you need. You can pull screenProps off the props and use it your screen or component (I wired it up in the constructor in this example), use getStateForAction to setState in your component driven off the router events.

Here is an example (some code removed for clarity)

***App.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';

import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import { HomeScreen } from './src/screens/HomeScreen.android';
import { LanguageSelectScreen } from './src/screens/LanguageSelectScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
    isTilted: false,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading  />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <MyApp screenProps={MyAppNavigator.router} />
      );
    }
  }
}

const MyAppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    PlayerNameScreen: {
      screen: PlayerNameScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
    initialRouteName: 'PlayerNameScreen',
  },
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MyAppNavigator,
    },
    MyModal: {
      screen: LanguageSelectScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);

export const MyApp = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

***HomeScreen.android.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: () => 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon
        name="checkerboard"
        type="material-community"
        size={25}
        color={tintColor}
      />
    ),
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const router = props.screenProps;

    const defaultGetStateForAction = router.getStateForAction;

    router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING':
          if (action.willShow == false) {
            console.log('CLOSED');
            this.setState({ isTilted: false });
          } else if (action.willShow == true) {
            this.setState({ isTilted: true });
            console.log('OPEN');
          }
          break;
      }

      return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
    };

    this.state = {
      isTilted: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isTilted } = this.state;

    // ... render using isTilted
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now in react navigation 5 you can directly access the status of your drawer using this approach :

`useIsDrawerOpen()` **is a Hook to detect if the drawer is open in a parent navigator.**

For exemple in your view you can test if your drawer is open or not directly using this approach :

```
import { useIsDrawerOpen } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const MainContainer = () => {
   return (
    <View style={(useIsDrawerOpen()) ? styles.conatinerOpenStyle : styles.containerClosedStyle}>
        <Text>{console.log("Test drawer  "+useIsDrawerOpen())}</Text>

    </View>
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar to `asdfghjklm`.

Here's my code which is working perfectly, even when you use a swipe to open - and then use a button to close it:

```
openCloseDrawer = (props) => {
  if (props.navigation.state.index == 1) {
    props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');
  } else {
    props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
  }
}
```

I execute this function when the user taps on the "Open/Close Drawer" button.

Comment: Dont understand why this was downvoted - this works!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Brad Bumbalough,  fredrivett (thank you mans) solution I find a more fast response solution (the other solution delays secons in some uses).

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = StackLogadoDrawer.router.getStateForAction;

StackLogadoDrawer.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING':
      if (action.willShow == false) {
        console.log('CERRADO');
      } else if (action.willShow == true) {
        console.log('ABIERTO');
      }
      break;
    }

  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

This is fired just immediately actions occurs (or very near).

It works on gestures or calling openDrawer()

Anyway I think this is a "must have" easy and direct way in the API

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not really seeing much. One way would be to control the opening/closing of the drawer manually using:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose'); // close drawer
```

That way you can wrap your close/open events in a function where you can do whatever you want before opening/closing.

The only other possible solution I saw in their docs was using a custom `contentComponent`. You can pass a function to the `onItemPress(route)` event, so maybe you can try hooking into that.

Comment: The problem is the DrawerNavigator handles taps to outside the drawer by itself, so my manual calls to navigate would be bypassed.

contentComponent would work if I needed to do something when those items were pressed. I'm actually trying to just hide the status bar while the drawer is open.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I'm surprised they don't have a built-in event for that. A dirty/hacky way would be to just attach a click event listener to the drawer toggle using vanilla JS. Just put it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method in the component where the DrawerNavigator is. So each time a user clicks to open the drawer, you're firing off your own event.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but again the issue is when the user closes the drawer, not opens. I have no way to capture that event.

Comment: How are they closing the drawer? By clicking out? You could attach a click handler to the `body` and then check to see if the drawer is open or closed by checking it's css. It can definitely be done, just depends on how hacky you are okay with lol good luck

Comment: I'm doing this in React Native, not on the web. I'd essentially have to calculate where the user is tapping in comparison to the open drawer. Looks like you can hook into dispatch actions if you hook up Redux. I'll likely do that, though I'm not at a point where I need Redux.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't see react native anywhere in the past. Good luck hope you figure something out

Answer (score 0):

**This is working fine in React-Native, not sure about React**.

For my case I had to change the **StatusBar** so I did not need to know wether the Drawer is closed fully or not, So below code worked for me...

```
props.navigation.state.drawerMovementDirection === 'closing'
        ? //it is closing not fully closed
        : (props.navigation.state.drawerMovementDirection === 'opening' ||
            props.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen) && (
          //fully opened or opening 
        )
```

If you don't need to know immediate then you can use below code, and this will work fine and will give you accurate answer whether the Drawer is Open or Not!

**Note: This will be delayed answer, in my case it was taking 1 sec.**

```
        props.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen?
                //open
                :
                //close;
```

If the solution does't work I am very sorry, but above all answer did not worked! So this is the version which is working for me:))

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const _unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('state', (data) => {
        var array = data.data.state.routes[0].state.history;
        const mydata = array.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('status'))
        console.log('data--->', mydata)
        if (mydata) {
            console.log('daawer close ')
        } else {
            console.log('daawer open ')
        }

    });
    return _unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In hooks `useDrawerStatue` solves it

```
import { useDrawerStatus } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
...

const isDrawerOpen = useDrawerStatus() === 'open'
```

if you don't use hooks you can get the indicator from `navigation.getState()` inside `history` you have one object with a `drawer` type when the drawer is open, but is not so pretty way :)

Answer (score -1):

Without Redux integration can be used **onNavigationStateChange** on router component. Just intercept drawer actions: **DrawerOpen** and **DrawerClose**.

Example:

```
  handleNavigationState = (previous, next, action) => {    
    if (action.routeName === 'DrawerOpen') {
      this.props.setDrawerState(true);
    } else if (action.routeName === 'DrawerClose') {
      this.props.setDrawerState(false);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationState} />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late, but for anyone who is looking for an answer:

The logic for the drawer being open/closed is in:

`this.props.navigation.state.routes[0].index`

It's 0 for closed, 1 for open.

You can also toggle the Drawers with

`this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')`

instead of

`this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');`

or

`this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');`

It seems to be more convenient for me and I have not happened upon any problems yet. Although it's nice to know whether they are toggled or not in order to invoke other actions.

I truly believe React-Navigation has one of the worst documentation that I have ever seen. There are commands that nobody knows about. I could not find the DrawerToggle action in the documents, and I only happened upon it through using console.log(this.props.navigation);