# Hide StatusBar in React Native when Drawer is opened

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a way to hide the `StatusBar` only in certain components/when `NavigationDrawer` is opened? Right now, it is hidden everywhere.

I have a component

```
export default class Comp1 extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (    
            <StatusBar hidden = {true} />
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Which I implement into another Component

```
export default class Comp2 extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (    
            <Comp1 ... />
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Which is mounted into `react navigation`.

Doing it that way, the `StatusBar` is hidden on all screens. Is there a way to hide the `StatusBar` when something is clicked? Or do I have to implement it differently in the Component.

Comment: You can pass property to StatusBar component like this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/statusbar.html#usage-with-navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy & Pasted from ufxmeng [ufxmeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574976/status-of-react-navigation-drawer-open-or-closed/45119464#45119464) and edited a little:

```
import {
  StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    //...
});

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

MyDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerClose') {
        StatusBar.setHidden(false);
    }

    if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerOpen') {
        StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }


    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

See here https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/673b9d2877d7e84fbfbe2928305ead7e51b04835/docs/api/routers/Routers.md
and here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/699

Comment: what If i want to call a custom component method like import DrawerContainer from '../Containers/DrawerContainer'; DrawerContainer.setHidden(false);

Answer (score 0):

The way to do such a thing is to pass a prop from the components above it.

if in Comp2 you pass a prop to Comp1 for instance hiddenBool. You can set that value to be whatever you want it to be true/false in Comp2. Then when the prop reaches Comp1 and tries to render the status bar it will pass that prop rather than always passing true.

Same with onClick function, make the onClick set a prop to false/true and that will update your component .