# Passing props from a root component through a BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app root component looks like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <RootTabs doThings={this.doThings} />
  }
}
```

The `RootTabs` component is created by [createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html) from react-navigation:

```
const RootTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Movies: {
    screen: Movies
  },
  Actors: ... // etc
})
```

My problem is, I would like to transmit data (as a prop if possible) from the root component (`App`) to the `Movies` component, but `Movies` do not receive the `doThings` prop.

**How to transmit props through a `BottomTabNavigator` to children?**

**If that's not possible, what would be the most simple way for a children component to call a method on a root component, when they are separated by a `BottomTabNavigator`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using screenProps

screenProps is documented on this [page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props)

Answered referred from [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1931)

Minimal Example would be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation, screenProps } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome, {screenProps.user.name}!</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')} title="Go to Profile" />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation, screenProps } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>My Profile</Text>
        <Text>Name: {screenProps.user.name}</Text>
        <Text>Username: {screenProps.user.username}</Text>
        <Text>Email: {screenProps.user.email}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Back to Home" />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
})

class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const screenProps = {
      user: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        username: 'johndoe123',
        email: 'john@doe.com',
      },
    }

    return (
      <AppNavigator screenProps={screenProps} />
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

HomeScreen and ProfileScreen are components defined as screens for AppNavigator.
In the example above, I am passing the user data from the top-level, root component MyApp to both HomeScreen and ProfileScreen.

Since there is a AppNavigator between MyApp and the screen components, we will need to pass the user to screenProps prop of AppNavigator, so that the AppNavigator will pass it down to the screens. Any other prop except screenProps will not be passed down.

MyApp <-- user data here .

- AppNavigator <-- the StackNavigator, the middle man. must use screenProps to pass user data down .

  - HomeScreen <-- will receive user data from this.props.screenProps.user instead of this.props.user .
  - ProfileScreen <-- same as HomeScreen

Comment: Thanks, `screenProps` works. But why is it documented only on `createStackNavigator` and not `createBottomTabNavigator`? It's crazy to have such a bad documentation.

Comment: @vmarquet Yeah its really hard to find screenProps from the official documentation.. its a different section .. they have to failed to document things separately