# How to disable swipe to open but not for closing in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I want to disable swipe to open the drawer navigation but not for closing?

I found solutions for android but not for react-native.
Currently I'm using this:

```
drawerLockMode: 'locked-open'
```

which works,but I can't close it with swipe.

I'm opening the drawer with hamburger menu icon like this:

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
```

Is here someone who already did this?
Is there a way to set `drawerLockMode` globally?
Does `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed` props exist?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me, and I think its simple and easy:

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from "../router/router";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Drawer extends Component {
  state = {
    lockMode: "locked-closed"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerNavigator
        screenProps={{
          drawerLockMode: this.state.lockMode
        }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState, action) => {
          if (
            action.type === "Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING" &&
            !action.willShow
          )
            this.setState({ lockMode: "locked-closed" });
          if (
            action.type === "Navigation/MARK_DRAWER_SETTLING" &&
            action.willShow
          ) {
            this.setState({ lockMode: "unlocked" });
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-navigation, you can get the event that is fired when anything get changed related to the navigation. Even if it is a drawer-open or drawer-close event. (I can't put up a working example right now.)

for more information follow these links.
[Status of React Navigation drawer? (open or closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574976/status-of-react-navigation-drawer-open-or-closed)
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

Try to get the event object information to detect and override the behavior.

Comment: this helped a bit,but I still don't know how to change the `drawerLockMode` dynamically.

Comment: Don't use that. Can't you use the isDrawerOpen boolean to check if it is already open and identify the current state of the drawer? I am sorry I cannot provide an example.

Comment: U mean inside `createDrawerNavigation`?

Comment: Yeah try and see

Comment: It won't work like that because its called only once.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `react-native-gesture-handler` module to `swipe`.

You can run

```
 yarn add react-native-gesture-handler

OR

npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
```

AND `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

Update your `MainActivity.java` file (or wherever you create an instance of `ReactActivityDelegate`), so that it overrides the method responsible for creating `ReactRootView` instance and then use the root view wrapper provided by this library. Do not forget to import `ReactActivityDelegate`, `ReactRootView`, and `RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView`:

```java
package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.example;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
+ import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }

+  @Override
+  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
+    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
+      @Override
+      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
+       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
+      }
+    };
+  }
}
```

[For more information,](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html) see

Comment: This is not what I need. I'm opening the drawer with swipe,but I want to close it with swipe

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something built in for this problem